# How to use my component in different Angular 2+ projects

Tags: angular, angular-components

I want to create a common component to use in my `website` and `admin-site` projects. These projects are in different project solutions.

So I need a `CommonComponent` and use it in any of these projects. But the CommonComponent contains so many subcomponents. So I do not want to copy the common component folders and files to other projects.

Is there any way to do this in angular 2+ projects?

Answer (score 0):

You can try Angular 6 CLI which supports multiple projects in the single workspace. Here is the proposed Project Folder structure

- Frontend
- Admin
- Library

  - Common Component
  - Child Component1
  - Child Component2

You can import the Library Module into the Frontend and admin module.